# Formula that would check a column of cells and say if he found an exact word

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Alright, so I want a formula that would search in a column of words a specific word, I was helped at  making one but it only logs the first one and stops there (even though it's not the one I want it to find)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A50, IMPORTRANGE("(sheetid)", "Project Automation Checker!B1:D50"), {2,3}, 0))).
```

I want it to find the word "CT" in column D of the Project Automation Checker.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n8DF771658l-7lIMu2Jx7YF9ZoHGb3H8UA0eOVd8iaE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to check for an exact match you can use regex like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(D2:D9, "^CT$"), "CT found", "CT NOT found"))
```

[image: 0]